# How could I cook industry like foie gras?

Tags: substitutions, flavor, seasoning, additives

I would like to learn the industrial skills that allow them to achieve such successful commercial products like the cheap and addictive foie gras.

I know that in many cases, it is required to have some special machinery.

Customers usually buy it without caring if it is not really foie gras.

Comment: What is "Industry Like" foie gras ? and the word "Cheap" does not usually go with Foie Gras which is still a luxury product and what does "Customers usually buy it without caring if it is not really foie gras." mean ?

Comment: I removed your recipe request as it is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: I am voting to close as I do not understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering.

Answer (score 9):

[Foie Gras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras) is fatty goose or duck liver. There is no machine or process to make it. It is harvested from the animals themselves. Restaurants have providers for their product. You will have to find one for yourself.

I know of no legitimate substitute for Foie Gras that anyone would not care about. People pay a lot of money for Foie Gras and would be quite displeased if they found they were being fed a cheap alternative.

If you are refering to paté made from Foie Gras then you could stretch the final product with the use of chicken livers. I'm uncertain how much cheaper this is though and once again be careful you aren't deceiving anyone.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by bruglesco, you can't fake proper fois gras. However, you can make a paté that's sometimes known as '*Faux Gras*'. It typically includes a lot of butter (often clarified), and chicken livers. (Google 'faux gras' for recipes.)

It's not quite *Fois Gras*, but it's not bad either.